# SQL statement: SET DATEFIRST 5

Tags: sql, sql-server, azure, spotfire

I have a statement like this that would not work on SQL Azure/Spotfire. I wanted to make the timestamp start from Friday-Thursday while the FirstDayOfweek pulls in once every week.

errors message
External error:

> Parse error at line: 1, column: 16: Incorrect syntax near 'SET'.

```sql
SET DATEFIRST 5;
SELECT DATEADD(wk, 0, DATEADD(DAY, 1-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, Daily.Timestamp), DATEDIFF(dd, 0, Daily.Timestamp))) as 'FirstDayOfWeek'
```

Comment: Thanks Dale, This is the actiual query, I had included bracket but still wouldn't work. The wk and dd is just ad abbreviation .SET DATEFIRST 5;SELECT DATEADD(wk, 0, DATEADD(DAY, 6-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [odt_nd].[odt_ne].[Daily].Timestamp), DATEDIFF(dd, 0, [odt_ne].[Daily].Timestamp))) as

Comment: Thanks Dale, This is the actiual query, I had included bracket but still wouldn't work. The wk and dd is just ad abbreviation .SET DATEFIRST 5;SELECT DATEADD(wk, 0, DATEADD(DAY, 6-DATEPART(WEEKDAY, [odt_nd].[odt_ne].[Daily].Timestamp), DATEDIFF(dd, 0, [odt_ne].[Daily].Timestamp))) as 'FirstDayOfWeek' Spotfire is a visualization application like BI, its connected with Azure.